# Heap memory Solr and Elasticsearch

Tags: solr, elasticsearch

I'm just reading the book **Mastering Apache Solr** and the writer recommends to set the minimum heap size (`-Xms`) to `2GB` and the maximum heap size (`-Xmx`) to `12GB`.

Is `2GB` necessary? I just use a `512MB` server (which is low, I know) for Solr and I found it already useful. Only sometimes indexing fails, probably because of that. We don't have 100.000 records yet, but it already helps with a quick and powerful search engine.

But... I just got started with Solr, so I just want to ask:

- Can I use Solr with a couple of GB memory?
- Does an alternative like Elasticsearch use less memory?

Just want to save money as much as possible, and I didn't read about the memory usage earlier. As far as I read [here](http://www.datanami.com/2015/01/22/solr-elasticsearch-question/) Solr is a better choice for us because we use it mainly for text-search. But if any of you have any better advice, I would like to hear so :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solr heap size must be set according your business. Set `-Xms=2G` and `-Xmx=12G` is just a recommendation to lots of popular Solr applications but it's not mandatory. You need to assess your requirements and set the heap to work well for you. I really recommend you to use at least `2G` on heap. There is a part of heap used by Solr just to maintains the server up and `512m` probably will not be enough.

Comment: Alright, thank you for your response. That's clear. I just upgraded the heap-size, figured out it was still minimum 8MB, max 128MB -_-.